# How to install Java 8 on machine with other Java versions

Tags: java, java-8

I installed Java 8 (jdk-8u60-windows-x64.exe) on machine with several other versions.

After installation I see the following message

```
d:\Userprofiles\user>java -version
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

I can change `JAVA_HOME` to the new location but this does not fix the above message.

When I edit the registry and change `1.8` in serveral registry keys to `1.7` I have a working configuration again. But this is still `1.7.`

Changing `JAVA_HOME` does not seem to have any effect. When I change it to my new installed JDK

```
d:\Userprofiles\user>java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)

d:\Userprofiles\user>echo %JAVA_HOME%
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

What do I need to do to have 1.8 working on my machine? `JAVA_HOME` seems obsolete now, should I change the registry? What should I do to change registry so that picks up the 1.8 version?

Comment: Who said `JAVA_HOME` is obsolete?  If I were you, I would uninstall _both_ Java 7 and 8, and then reinstall them from scratch into _separate_ directories.  After this, configure your environment variables to choose one for running.

Comment: Why did you ask exactly the same question again?

Comment: Java has NEVER used JAVA_HOME. This variable is used by several tools like Ant, Maven, Gradle, but not by Java itself. You must modify your PATH to point to the jdk/bin directory you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not enough just to introduce the value for `%JAVA_HOME%` (actually, Java doesn't care if there is or there isn't such environment variable).

What you have to do is to append `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` directory to the `Path` environment variable, so that you get the `java.exe` that matches the `%JAVA_HOME%` version, without having to write the full path to the `java.exe` executable that you want to trigger.

So, either do this:

- set a value for the `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable
- append `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` to the `Path` environment variable

or just

- append `<the-java-home-directory>/bin` to the `Path` variable.

Personally, I would prefer to maintain a value for `JAVA_HOME`, as it is needed by tools like Maven, Hadoop, etc.

Comment: Problem was indeed my `Path` variable. `JAVA_HOME` was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many JDK's installed as you want, and you don't even need them in the PATH, or to set JAVA_HOME.

The first one found in the PATH will be the default one. Remember to only install the JDK, not the JRE that always comes with the JDK, i.e. unselect the 3rd option when installing.

I have **9** JDK's installed, and I can run all of them without changing anything. All you have to do is qualify the executable:

```
C:\>prog\java32\jdk1.4.2_19\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.4.2_19"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.4.2_19-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.4.2_19-b04, mixed mode)

C:\>prog\java32\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode)

C:\>prog\java32\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\>prog\java32\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\>prog\java32\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\>prog\java64\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode)

C:\>prog\java64\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

C:\>prog\java64\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

C:\>prog\java64\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

That was the output in a single Command Prompt, without ever setting the PATH.

Comment: Any particular reason you need both 32 bits and 64 bits copies? Just curious.

Comment: @Gimby Just for testing.

Comment: *"The first one found in the PATH will be the default one"* - as an addendum to that, on Windows the Java runtime installation dumps some executables in the windows system folder to be able to speak of a "default Java". That can cause some confusion if you have multiple Java installations installed, as the system folder in the path can mess with what is found first. That's why I put the Java I want to be the default at the very front of the Path myself, before any windows folders even.