# Can I have more than one java vm in my system?

Tags: java

I'm using java 9 with jshell for testing java; so, many applets use java 8.
Can I install java 8 and java 9 on my windows system?

Comment: Do you..use a lot of applets?

Comment: I assume Java 9 is backwards compatible with Java 8.

Comment: You can keep installing different versions of Java until you run out of disk space. I have 6 versions on my machine.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have 9 versions (all the way back to Java 1.4), and I don't even have Java 9 yet. Testing backwards compatibility can be cumbersome. Wish all production code could be upgraded to latest version, that would definitely simplify life.

Comment: @Andreas we have a teamcity server which triggers builds in different versions. We do low level stuff so have to test Windows and Linux too. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only install one Java version that affects the Web Browser (JRE installation), but you can install as many JDK's as you want, just don't installed the JRE that comes with the JDK.

The Web Browser will use the lastest installed JRE that matches the browsers 32/64-bit mode.

Command-line programs, like `javac` and `java`, will use the JDK that is on the PATH. You can also fully qualify the path to the programs to override the PATH, e.g. `C:\path\to\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe`.

IDE's can usually use any installed JDK.

As example, see this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32963951/5221149).