# How to choose between multiple java minor versions through command line argument?

Tags: java, cmd, arguments, java-7, configuration-management

I recently found a java post showing its possible to select which JDK major install is used to run a java program at the command line using **java -version:1.#**. This will let me choose between major versions of java, but not if there are multiple minor versions available.

Does anyone know if its possible to choose between multiple minor updates of java like java 1.7.67 and java 1.7.80?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with this? Is there a reason you wouldn't use the latest minor version?

Comment: We are testing our application on a specific java version. We want to go to a newer java version but we don't know which minor update we are going to. I want the option to choose between a few different minor updates so I'm ready when our leadership team finally settles on a version.

Comment: That's not necessary. Choosing between minor versions would be useful only if you were to test JDK bugs. Use the latest update, and save your time for something more useful.

Comment: If you install multiple versions, you choose which one to use by qualifying the `java` command. See [my previous answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32963951/5221149).